# NSSound on the iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-audio

I've been looking for a while how to play sound on the iphone, and I think it's something along the lines of:

```
[[NSSound soundNamed:@"cat.mp3"] play];
```

But the NSSound is on the AppKit ... any suggestions ? I know there is a really simple answer to this, but today my searches are not rendering any result ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the new AVFoundation class is the easiest way to play sound on the iPhone, though it is for firmware 2.2 only:

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];  
[audioPlayer play];
```

you just need this import in the class that uses it:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll try this one tonight

Answer (score 7):

Audio Toolbox system sounds are great for short async playback.

```
// Initialize
CFBundleRef mainBundle;
mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

// Init each sound
CFURLRef      tapURL;
SystemSoundID tapSound;
tapURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("tap"), CFSTR("aif"), NULL);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(tapURL, &tapSound);

// Play the sound async
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(tapSound);
```

I haven't gotten MP3s to work with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`. But it plays AIF files perfectly.