# Can anyone point me a direction i can follow to learn how to handle audio in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio

My real objective is to be able to use 1 audio file and create X amount of different pitches and then playing them in the app using some code to handle the timing.

TIA for any helpful insight

Answer (score 0):

You can read [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/musicaudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388192/nssound-on-the-iphone/388498#388498), which recommends using the [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html) framework.

Core Audio is supposed to be fairly low level. Great if you need more flexibility/control, but AVFoundation may be more appropriate for your app.

Comment: If the OP is creating sound files of different pitches, he might have to resort to Core Audio. Can't really tell based on the question, but it looks a little low-level.